# Non-standard evaluation with dplyr and shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr

I am hoping someone can help me with non standard evaluation when passing variable names to dplyr within a shiny app. My intention is to be able to select variables to pass to the functions `select` and `top_n`. I know the `select` function has an equivalent `select_` for NSE, but I am battling to get that working within the shiny app too.

I have included an example below which has two commented lines that are those I'm hoping to get working. The first commented line is intended to drop the column identified by `input$var_to_rank` from the output table while the second commented line (using `top_n`) should set the number of top ranked rows to show, and the column to base those ranks on.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
data(iris)

shinyApp(
  ui = basicPage(
selectInput("species", "species", choices = levels(iris$Species)),
selectInput("var_to_drop", "Variable to drop", choices = names(iris)[3:4]),
selectInput("var_to_rank", "Variable to rank", choices = names(iris)[1:2]),
numericInput("n.obs", "Top N", 5),

    tableOutput("table")
),

server = function(input, output) {


output$table <- renderTable({

  iris %>% 
    filter(Species == input$species) %>%
  # select_(quote(-input$var_to_drop)) %>%
    top_n(5, Sepal.Length)
  # top_n(n.obs, input$var_to_rank)
  })
}
)
```

Thanks very much for any help and apologies if this question is answered elsewhere.

Comment: A simple fix to the first comment is to use `get` -- `select(-get(input$var_to_drop))`

Comment: Thanks Jason. You're right. I'd tried `get` with `top_n` unsuccessfully and had given up on it, but it works with `select`. I also tried replacing the use of `top_n` with `filter_(min_rank(desc(input$var_to_rank)) <= input$n.obs)`,but this didn't work either. Nor did adopting this approach together with `get`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve your first problem: this is how you can achieve what you want with NSE

```
select_(lazyeval::interp(~ -var, var = as.name(input$var_to_drop)))
```

There might be an easier/shorter way, but this works. I know it can be much simpler if you want to include rather than drop columns, I can't figure out shorter code that works with the `-`

---

For your second problem, you can achieve the same effect as `top_n` like this

```
cutoff <- iris %>% .[[input$var_to_rank]] %>% sort %>% rev %>% .[input$n.obs]
iris %>% filter_(lazyeval::interp(~ var >= cutoff, var = as.name(input$var_to_rank)))
```

---

Just for completeness sake, I'm leaving the original answer to the second problem:
For your second problem, this is a solution that works slightly differently. I'm not sure if this is what you want.  Using `top_n(5)` can potentially return more than 5 rows so I'm doing a similar thing but ensuring that only 5 rows get returned

```
iris %>% arrange_(input$var_to_rank) %>% tail(input$n.obs)
```

Comment: Thanks for this response. The use of tail is a neat workaround, but in my use case I need to preserve tied ranks in the output unfortunately. As you say, this means than additional rows will be returned.

Comment: See my edited answer, I modified my solution to mimic `top_n` using NSE. It's not the cleanest though, you can refine it

Comment: Great. Thank you very much. This solves the problem. A note for others there's an '=' sign missing. The corrected line is select_(lazyeval::interp(~ -var, var = as.name(input$var_to_drop))). I also modified to calculate the cutoff after first filtering by species rather than beforehand, adding the cutoff value to the iris dataframe using mutate, then applying the cutoff filter. Thanks again.

Comment: Ah sorry about that, edited my answer to fix that typo.